# determining symplecticity (if that's a word)

Tags: lie-groups, nt.number-theory, linear-algebra

Suppose you have a matrix $M$ in $SL(n, \mathbb{Z}).$ Question: is there a necessary and sufficient condition for $M$ to be conjugate to $N \in Sp(n, \mathbb{Z}).$ It is clearly necessary that the characteristic polynomial of $M$ be palindromic, but I would assume that this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the condition that $n$ is even. I do not think there is a better criterion than the tautology.

The unipotent matrix

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&1&2&3\\\ 0&1&4&5\\\ 0&0&1&1\\\0&0&0&1\end{array}
 \right] $$ is not conjugate to a symplectic matrix in $SL(4,\mathbb{Z})$ (although it is conjugate to a symplectic matrix in $SL(4,\mathbb{C})$.

On the other hand the matrix

$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1&0&0&1\\\ 0&1&0&0\\\ 0&0&1&0\\\0&0&0&1\end{array}
 \right] $$

is conjugate to a symplectic matrix.

Both facts can be easily verified by using Maple.

Comment: Why is that matrix not conjugate to a symplectic matrix? Is there an obvious obstruction?

Comment: The problem reduces to a system of polynomial equations. That system can be simplified and gives a quadratic equation whose discriminant is negative. You can do it yourself with Maple or any other CAS. 

Comment: Ah, so you are saying that the obstruction is getting it over the reals. After that we are down to a Diophantine problem, which is kind of what I was more interested in, but it's a start...

Comment: Yes, there are no solutions over the reals (if I did not make errors). The sequence of polynomials corresponding to the first matrix has a Groebner basis (the one found by Maple had 56 polynomials, I am not sure it is optimal, perhaps I should have chosen a different order of variables). Then the standard procedure solves it. 